# Pip Installation Error - Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, pip

I have just installed **Python 2.7.5** on a **Windows 7 (32-bit)** box.

When trying to install **Scrapy** module via the Windows console I get the below error:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\compaq\app
data\local\temp\pip_build_COMPAQ\pyOpenSSL
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\COMPAQ\pip\pip.log
```

I have read other threads on this, suggesting that setup tools be re-installed or updated. I have already attempted this (the latest setup tools exist) but the scrapy install error remains.

The below is the full install script and failure:

```
  C:\Windows\system32>pip install scrapy
  Downloading/unpacking scrapy
    Running setup.py (path:c:\users\compaq\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_COMPAQ\scr
  apy\setup.py) egg_info for package scrapy

      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\build'
  Downloading/unpacking Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
  Downloading/unpacking w3lib>=1.2 (from scrapy)
    Downloading w3lib-1.5.tar.gz
    Running setup.py (path:c:\users\compaq\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_COMPAQ\w3l
  ib\setup.py) egg_info for package w3lib

  Downloading/unpacking queuelib (from scrapy)
    Downloading queuelib-1.1.1.tar.gz
    Running setup.py (path:c:\users\compaq\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_COMPAQ\que
  uelib\setup.py) egg_info for package queuelib

  Downloading/unpacking lxml (from scrapy)
    Running setup.py (path:c:\users\compaq\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_COMPAQ\lxm
  l\setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
      Building lxml version 3.3.0.
      Building without Cython.
      ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.

      ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
  *

      Using build configuration of libxslt
      C:\HACK\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution
  option: 'bugtrack_url'
        warnings.warn(msg)

      warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
  Downloading/unpacking pyOpenSSL (from scrapy)
    Running setup.py (path:c:\users\compaq\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_COMPAQ\pyO
  penSSL\setup.py) egg_info for package pyOpenSSL

      error: Only found improper OpenSSL directories: ['C:\\RUBY\\RailsInstaller\\
  Git']
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      running egg_info

  creating pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info

  writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt


  writing pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\PKG-INFO

  writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\top_level.txt

  writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



  error: Only found improper OpenSSL directories: ['C:\\RUBY\\RailsInstaller\\Git'
  ]

  ----------------------------------------
  Cleaning up...
  Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\compaq\app
  data\local\temp\pip_build_COMPAQ\pyOpenSSL
  Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\COMPAQ\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 3):

`pip` tries to build packages from source. So you'll need development headers for libraries and `VS2008` compiler, all of which is rather painful to set up.

It's easier to download prebuilt binaries for failed packages from here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

And then retry installing `scrapy`.