# Error installing Scrapy: error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I'm trying to install Scrapy using:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

However I get the error. Can someone suggest a solution?

[image]

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773766/378704). Traceback looks similar to yours.

Comment: Note that the recommended way to install scrapy on Windows is to [use Anaconda/Miniconda](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows).

Answer (score 2):

Download `sasl` source code, `.whl` packages [from here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl). After executing the command:

```
 pip install sasl-0.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

the sasl package should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Installed Windows 10 SDK tools from Visual Tools (even though I have Windows 7) and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have exit out your python editor and or running python scripts, also make sure you have run CMD as admin. I had this error earlier today just before posting it went away. (after I run as admin)

Comment: I just ran as an administrator (the cmd) and the error remains

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650763/pip-installation-error-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code?rq=1[link] This user almost has the same problem as yours. You could try the solution they gave him.